# File saving forces jtable cell to commit all changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my application there is a table and users can edit the cells.
When you hit save all of the data is written out.

At the moment, it is possible for a user to double-click on a cell, type in some text, and then hit save. Since the user did not press enter or anything to commit the changes to the table, the data that is written out does not include whatever the user was typing in.

I would like to make it so that when I invoke the save function, any cells that are currently being edited will have their contents forcefully changed to what is typed in before the actual file saving occurs. How can this be done?

Comment: have you tried to wrap your call to the `save()` method into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`?

Comment: I have not worked with something like that before can you provide more information on how it would work?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet s/he want to rollback if isn't JButton pressed,

Comment: @Keikoku this could be annyoing for the users, whats difference (your logic) if I edited one cell then to save, edited 2-3-5 cells then to save (which one can be saved, all, one, first, last) and edited whole JTables view and then ..., I miss there JButton for RollBack, not hardcoded logics, lets that as users decision, if s/he want to save then save, if not then nothing happened, because s/he can to use JButton with Restore/RollBack, never underestimate the users, they are able to any miracles

Comment: I like how spreadsheet programs like Excel are implemented where I can just hit ctrl+S while I am editing a cell, and then the cell stops editing and the file is written out. I don't want to have to remember to press enter before ctrl+s'ing. Rollback is not necessary: if the cell is currently being edited, and they hit save, then whatever they had typed in is assumed to be what they want to be saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the action listener handling the save button you can do something like:

```
if (table.isEditing())
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

(from http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/)